# Modeling rare event

Tags: logistic, binary-data, cart, unbalanced-classes, rare-events

I'm working with a dataset with roughly 14K records, and am trying to predict a binary variable (death). While the total dataset size is sufficient, the patients with deaths I'm trying to predict make up roughly 1.5% of the total population. To date I've used decision trees but with no success.

Are there any other methods for such a scenario?  I'm also considering predicting probabilities of death as opposed dead/not dead.  Any references would be great!

Comment: Modeling a binary variable with a rare outcome is difficult.  Can you get time from some meaningful starting point (when cancer is found, or from treatment) until death?